# GDAL setgeotransform()

Tags: c++, gdal

I have been trying to use GDAL library to add geoinformation to an image. From the documentation from GDAL web page I could find that I could use GDAlSetGeotransform(), for that I need a six parameters GDAL transformation information. Among the six parameters, the x-rotation and y rotation are considered 0 for north up image. But in my case I don't have north up image. So how could I get these rotation values if I have four corner coordinates of the image. 
Or there is any other technique to add geoinformation to my image if I have four corner coordinates of the image.

Comment: This question would be better suited at [GIS.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: See [question on GIS.se](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/140547/1872)

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found is to estimate a transform matrix using least squares.  This takes the following form.

Given N (4+) sets of pixel values and their matching world coordinates, build a pair of transforms.  Then solve for the transforms.  The following example is shown in octave.  If using C++, just use Eigen or OpenCV and build a Moore-Penrose SVD Pseudo-Inverse Solver.

```
#!/usr/bin/env octave -qf

%  Apply Geo Transform
function [Wx, Wy] = Apply_GeoTransform( Px, Py, adfGeoTransform )

    %  Multiply
    Wx = adfGeoTransform(1,2) * Px + adfGeoTransform(1,3) * Py +     adfGeoTransform(1,1);
    Wy = adfGeoTransform(1,5) * Px + adfGeoTransform(1,6) * Py + adfGeoTransform(1,4);

endfunction

%
%   Main Function
%   
%  Create Sample Inputs
W = [ 0, 50;
     50,  0;
      0,-50;
    -50,  0];

P = [ 0, 0;
     10, 0;
     10,10;
      0,10];

%  Build Input Transform (A)
Ai = [P(1,1), P(1,2), 1;
      P(2,1), P(2,2), 1;
      P(3,1), P(3,2), 1;
      P(4,1), P(4,2), 1];

%  Build Output Solution Pairs
Bx = [W(1,1);
      W(2,1);
      W(3,1);
      W(4,1)];

By = [W(1,2);
      W(2,2);
      W(3,2);
      W(4,2)];

%   Solve For Inverse x and y
Xi = Ai \ Bx;
Yi = Ai \ By;

%   Construct Actual Transform
adfGeoTransform = [Xi(3,1), Xi(1,1), Xi(2,1), Yi(3,1), Yi(1,1), Yi(2,1)];

%   Test Result
[Wx1, Wy1] = Apply_GeoTransform( 0, 0, adfGeoTransform );
[Wx2, Wy2] = Apply_GeoTransform(10, 0, adfGeoTransform );
[Wx3, Wy3] = Apply_GeoTransform(10,10, adfGeoTransform );
[Wx4, Wy4] = Apply_GeoTransform( 0,10, adfGeoTransform );
[Wx5, Wy5] = Apply_GeoTransform( 5, 5, adfGeoTransform );

printf('W1: %d, %d\n', Wx1, Wy1);
printf('W2: %d, %d\n', Wx2, Wy2);
printf('W3: %d, %d\n', Wx3, Wy3);
printf('W4: %d, %d\n', Wx4, Wy4);
printf('W5: %d, %d\n', Wx5, Wy5);
```